# Specify single Google Analytics property

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js

I have a website where two separate Google Analytics properties are used for tracking.

The first is:

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-11111111-1');
</script>
```

The second is:

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-22222222-2');
</script>
```

I'm also tracking the following event:

```
gtag('event', 'pageview', {'event_category': 'LoadContent'});
```

At the moment, the same event is being tracked across both GA properties, however, I only want it to be tracked for the first one. How can I specify that? I searched everywhere online but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
gtag('event', 'pageview', {
                           'event_category': 'LoadContent',
                           'send_to': 'UA-11111111-1'
});
```

sned_to will allow you to specify which property you want to send it to.